# Merging rows with shared information

Tags: r, merge

I have a data.frame with several rows which come from a merge which are not completely merged:

```
b <- read.table(text = "
      ID   Age    Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
68 HA-09   16   <NA>          <NA>       <NA>       5             NA
69 HA-09   16   <33% no/occasional       <NA>      NA             1")
```

How can I merge them by a column ?

Expected output :

```
      ID  Age     Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
69 HA-09   16  <33% no/occasional       <NA>       5             1
```

Note that some columns (other than ID) have the same value on both rows. These columns aren't part of the "primary key" of the database (AFAIK). So if there are several different values shouldn't be merged. Things I tried:

```
 merge(b[1, ], b[2, ], all = T) # Doesn't merge the rows, just the data.frames
 cast(b, ID ~ .) # I can count them but not merging them into a single row
 aggregate(b, by = list("ID", "Age"), c) # Error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach using `summarise_all`:

```
## using `na.strings` to identify NA entries in posted data
b <- read.table(text = "
      ID   Age    Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
68 HA-09   16   <NA>          <NA>       <NA>       5             NA
69 HA-09   16   <33% no/occasional       <NA>      NA             1", na.strings = c("NA", "<NA>"))

library(dplyr)
f <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  if (length(x) > 0) first(x) else NA
}
res <- b %>% group_by(ID,Age) %>% summarise_all(funs(f))
##Source: local data frame [1 x 7]
##Groups: ID [?]
##
##      ID   Age Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
##  <fctr> <int>    <fctr>        <fctr>      <lgl>   <int>         <int>
##1  HA-09    16      <33% no/occasional         NA       5             1
```

The definition of the function is to handle the case where all values is `NA`.

---

As @jdobres suggests, if there are more than one non-`NA` values that you want to merge (per each column), you may want to flatten all of these to a string representation using:

```
library(dplyr)
f <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  if (length(x) > 0) paste(x,collapse='-') else NA
}
res <- b %>% group_by(ID,Age) %>% summarise_all(funs(f))
```

In your posted data, the result would be the same as above because all columns that are summarized has at most one non-`NA` value.

Comment: This assumes that for each ID, each column will have exactly 1 non-NA value. OP's example is unclear on whether this is always the case. Rather than `first(x)`, you could do `paste(x, collapse = '-')` to preserve multiple values.

Comment: @jdobres: I agree. I would say, however, that conversion of the data to characters may also be not what the OP wants.

Comment: @jdobres I would prefer to keep two different rows if a ID has different information for a column

Comment: Also, this results in an error "Error: expecting a string"

Answer (score 2):

While I'm sure that it's possible with `dplyr` or `tidyr`, here's a `data.table` solution:

```
b <- read.table(text = "
      ID   Age    Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
                68 HA-09   16   <NA>          <NA>       <NA>       5             NA
                69 HA-09   16   <33% no/occasional       <NA>      NA             1",
                na.strings = c("NA", "<NA>"))

keycols <- c("ID", "Age")
library(data.table)
b_dt <- data.table(b)

filter_nas <- function(x){
  if(all(is.na(x))){
    return(unique(x))
  }
  return(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))
}

b_dt[, lapply(.SD, filter_nas ), by = mget(keycols)]


      ID Age Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
1: HA-09  16      <33% no/occasional         NA       5             1
```

Note, this only works if the keys are unique.

Comment: This assumes that the keycolumns don't change and are known, doesn't it?

Comment: They have to be known in some way if you want to be able to perform an operation. You could work them out dynamically (first consecutive columns with no NAs or something)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R method that should work, for a version of the data that you provided:

```
aggregate(b[-grep("^(ID|Age)$", names(b))], b[c("ID", "Age")], 
          FUN=function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else x[!is.na(x)][1])

   ID Age Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3  Bili.AHHS2cat
 1 HA-09  16      <33% no/occasional         NA       5  1
```

It uses `aggregate` together with an `if` `else` check. This will return the first element that is not missing if any should exist. I take the first element as there is at least one observation. The `i` in the code could be replaced by `length(x)` to select the last element.

As suggested by @jdobres in a comment to another answer, it would be possible to use `paste` with the collapse argument to combine multiple non-missing elements. This, of course would convert the type of the vector to character, which may not be desirable if the variable is numeric.

Note: I edited my original answer to include "Age" in the key, thanks to @sebastian-c for pointing this out.

---

If "Age" is not part of the key, then

```
aggregate(b[-grep("^(ID)$", names(b))], b["ID"], 
          FUN=function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else x[!is.na(x)][1])
```

will work.

**data**

```
b <- read.table(text = "
      ID   Age    Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
68 HA-09   16   NA          NA       NA       5             NA
69 HA-09   16   <33% no/occasional     NA      NA             1")
```

Comment: I love base R answers! I thought `Age` was in the key (ID over multiple years), but I guess there's no reason for it to be.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, @sebastian-c. I just updated my answer to include age.

Comment: I also like the base R answers. Age is not part of the key

Comment: I might be overthinking this, but why the first element?

Comment: In the final line of your question, you have `aggregate(b, by = list("ID", "Age"), c)`. The by argument here indicates that "Age" is part of the key. I'll add back the code that only uses "ID". For the second comment, I take the first element because it necessarily exists. A second element, for example might not. I'll add a note about this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Llopis's request to keep both rows if a given ID has different information for a column complicates matters. First let's create some example data that illustrates the situation:

```
b <- read.table(text = "ID   Age    Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
                HA-09   16   <NA>          <NA>       <NA>       5             NA
                HA-09   16   <33% no/occasional       <NA>      NA             1
                HA-10   20   no <NA> <NA> 2 NA
                HA-10   20   yes <NA> 0 NA NA",
                na.strings = c("NA", "<NA>"), header = T)

     ID Age Steatosis       Mallory Lille_dico Lille_3 Bili.AHHS2cat
1 HA-09  16      <NA>          <NA>         NA       5            NA
2 HA-09  16      <33% no/occasional         NA      NA             1
3 HA-10  20        no          <NA>         NA       2            NA
4 HA-10  20       yes          <NA>          0      NA            NA
```

This can still be accomplished, but the custom function for summarization (let's call it `f`) gets a little more complicated:

```
f <- function(x) {
    x <- x[!is.na(x$value),]
    if (nrow(x) > 0) {
        y <- unique(x[colnames(x) != 'row.ID'])
        y$row.ID <- 1:nrow(y)
        return(y)
    } else {
        return(data.frame())
    }
}
```

Notice that this function references a column called "row.ID", which we will create before applying the function:

```
library(tidyverse) # gives access to dplyr and tidyr packages

b2 <- gather(b, variable, value, -ID, -Age) %>% # gather the many columns into a simplified key/value pair of columns (one called 'variable', the other, 'value') for each ID
    group_by(ID, variable) %>% # perform subsequent operations per ID and variable
    mutate(row.ID = 1:n()) %>% # add a row identifier
    do(f(.)) %>% # apply our custom function
    spread(variable, value, convert = T) %>% # un-gather the variable/value columns
    ungroup # remove grouping metadata

      ID   Age row.ID Bili.AHHS2cat Lille_3 Lille_dico       Mallory Steatosis
* <fctr> <int>  <int>         <int>   <int>      <int>         <chr>     <chr>
1  HA-09    16      1             1       5         NA no/occasional      <33%
2  HA-10    20      1            NA       2          0          <NA>        no
3  HA-10    20      2            NA      NA         NA          <NA>       yes
```