# Merging two rows with some having missing values in R

Tags: r, merge, row, na

I would like to ask the R community how to merge two rows with the same ID (i.e. same participant) with some variables that are identical and others where there are NA's. In my example, I would like all the values 4-5-6 to appear on one row and therefore for the NA's (or empty cells) to be gone.

[image: This is an example of what my data looks like]

I have tried using dplyr without much success, and I have to do the merging by hand (which is quite time consuming and increases the risk for errors). Thank you in advance for your help with this problem!

Comment: Please do not use images.  Provide sample input data as R code that can be copied and pasted into R to reproduce the input.  I have done this for you this time in the Note at the end of my answer.  See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging rows with shared information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920870/merging-rows-with-shared-information)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Okay, thank you for the info.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Create sample data frame.
id <- c(rep('Participant 1', 2), rep('Participant 2', 2))
value1 <- rep('A', 4)
value2 <- rep('B', 4)
value3 <- rep('C', 4)
value4 <- c('x', NA, NA, 'x')
value5 <- c('x', NA, 'x', NA)
value6 <- c(NA, 'x', NA, 'x')

df <- data.frame(id, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Use dplyr to group the data and keep the non-NA value from the other columns.
df %>% group_by(id, value1, value2, value3) %>%
       summarise(value4 = max(value4, na.rm = T),
                 value5 = max(value5, na.rm = T),
                 value6 = max(value6, na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
  gather(var, val, Value4:Value6) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>% 
  spread(var, val)
```

using the data of @G.Grothendieck, this results in:

```
  ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6
1  1      A      B      C      x      x      x
2  2      A      B      C      x      x      x
```

Or another variation with `summarise_each` with the `max` approach of @G.Grothendieck:

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(ID, Value1, Value2, Value3) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(max(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

The `gather` and `spread` options can also be translated into a solution with `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(na.omit(melt(DF, id.vars = c('ID','Value1','Value2','Value3'))),
      ID + Value1 + Value2 + Value3 ~ variable,
      value.var = 'value')
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Using `DF` defined in the Note below try aggregating using the `compress` function defined below. This function removes NA values and appends an NA just in case all values were removed and then takes the first of what is left. No packages are used.

```
compress <- function(x) c(na.omit(x), NA)[1]
aggregate(DF[5:7], DF[1:4], compress)
```

giving:

```
  ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6
1  1      A      B      C      x      x      x
2  2      A      B      C      x      x      x
```

**2)** A simpler alternative if no participant has all NA values in any column is that we could eliminate the definition of `compress` and use `max` with `na.rm = TRUE` instead like this:

```
aggregate(DF[5:7], DF[1:4], max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6
1 A B C x x NA
1 A B C NA NA x
2 A B C NA x NA
2 A B C x NA x"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use `dplyr` try:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
    group_by(ID, Value1, Value2, Value3) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(toString(na.omit(.))))
```

**Result:**

```
     ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6
  <int>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1     1      A      B      C      x      x      x
2     2      A      B      C      x      x      x
```

**Note:**

- `DF` as defined by G. Grothendieck https://stackoverflow.com/a/40820313/5727278
- This builds off of docendo discimus's https://stackoverflow.com/a/27289383/5727278