# Merge rows with similar information

Tags: r, merge, na

I have data frame with several rows and I need to merge the rows with same ID.

```
a=read.csv("a.csv")
view(a)

ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6
1076    2940    NA  NA  2   NA  NA
1076    2940    1   A-  NA  302 549
1109    2940    NA  NA  3   NA  NA
1109    2940    NA  A-  NA  700 150
```

I need the results like

```
ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6
1076    2940    1   A-  2   302 549
1109    2940    NA  A-  3   700 150
```

I have already reviewed the answer to a similar problem ([Merging rows with shared information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920870/merging-rows-with-shared-information)). But I am getting an error in the results.

```
library(dplyr)
f <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  if (length(x) > 0) paste(x,collapse='-') else NA
}
a_merge <- a %>% group_by(ID)%>%summarise_all(list(f))
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error: Column `Value2` can't promote group 1 to character
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to create a condition with `if/else` to return NA when all the values in the column is `NA` or `else` get the `unique` non-NA elements in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise_all(list(~ list(if(all(is.na(.))) NA else unique(.[!is.na(.)]))))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#     ID Value1    Value2    Value3    Value4    Value5    Value6   
#  <int> <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
#1  1076 <int [1]> <int [1]> <chr [1]> <int [1]> <int [1]> <int [1]>
#2  1109 <int [1]> <lgl [1]> <chr [1]> <int [1]> <int [1]> <int [1]>
```

EDIT:

1) Wrapped in a `list`

2) @Gregor's comment - get only the `unique` non-NA elements

#### data

```
a <- structure(list(ID = c(1076L, 1076L, 1109L, 1109L), Value1 = c(2940L, 
2940L, 2940L, 2940L), Value2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA), Value3 = c(NA, 
"A-", NA, "A-"), Value4 = c(2L, NA, 3L, NA), Value5 = c(NA, 302L, 
NA, 700L), Value6 = c(NA, 549L, NA, 150L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Getting this error: `Error: Column `Value1` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2`

Comment: @Looper If there are more than one non-NA per group, do you want to collapse as a string or have as a `list`.  If it is a `list`, then wrap with `list` (updated)

Comment: I'll prefer as a list

Comment: Depending on OP's use case adding a `unique()` for `list(unique(.[!is.na(.)]))` might be preferable.

Comment: @akrun Getting this: Error: Column `Value2` can't promote group 1 to list

Comment: @Looper I think the issue is the `list` wrapping.  I changed it to `list(if(all`  Try it

Comment: Yes this is working. And, if need to combine those as a string?

Comment: @Looper In that case `toString(unique(.[!is.na(.)]))` and remove the `list` wrapper

Comment: @Looper `a %>%  group_by(ID) %>%summarise_all(list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA_character_ else toString(unique(.[!is.na(.)]))))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R approach,

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(i) 
                                       sapply(i, function(j) j[!is.na(j)][1]))), names(df))

#    ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6
#1 1076   2940      1     A-      2    302    549
#2 1109   2940   <NA>     A-      3    700    150
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `data.table` you can avoid converting all the columns to lists and only convert the ones where it's required.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, lapply(.SD, function(x)
          if(length(vals <- unique(x[!is.na(x)])) > 1)
            list(vals)
          else vals), 
  by = ID]

#      ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6
# 1: 1076   2940    2,1     A-      2    302    549
# 2: 1109   2940            A-      3    700    150
```

If you're using `toString` you can remove the `if` and simplify things. This should apply to dplyr also.

```
df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))),
  by = ID]
# 1: 1076   2940   2, 1     A-      2    302    549
# 2: 1109   2940            A-      3    700    150
```

Modified example data (added a case with >1 distinct value)

```
df <- fread('
ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6
1076    2940    2  NA  2   NA  NA
1076    2940    1   A-  NA  302 549
1109    2940    NA  NA  3   NA  NA
1109    2940    NA  A-  NA  700 150
')
```